# How to override the "Save Image" menu of WKWebView on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I want to develop an iOS native app using WKWebView.
when I loading a page e.g:  http://www.google.com
and When I long press "Google" logo, it will popup a UIAlertViewController with "Save Image"
"Copy"
"Cancel"
items.

but when I tap on "Save Image" the photo will be saved into system "photo library"
what I need is to "Save Image" to my app documents folder.

is there a way to implement it?

[image: I upload a screenshot for more detailed explanation: I mean the UIActionSheet]

[image: not the "copy past " menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

menu appear when you long press on WKWebview is  [UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimenucontroller) . You can customise it to add new items to it - new buttons with you custom action on it. But you cant Modify existing menu action.

If you want to copy image to some  other place with menu, Add new menu to save image to to document folder.

```
UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy Image"
                                                      action:@selector(customAction:)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have edited this question again.  to be more detailed, I mean the UIActionSheet liked control  which is in the first screenshot.  I guess you mentioned the second menu in WKWebview, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

just remove all the "long press" gesture recognisers or debug it and understand which exactly of the recognisers you need to remove:

```
for (UIView *subView in self.webView.scrollView.subviews) {
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recogniser in subView.gestureRecognizers) {
        if ([recogniser isKindOfClass:UILongPressGestureRecognizer.class]) {
            [subView removeGestureRecognizer:recogniser];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject js logic to prevent the default action, and pass event to native side.

You can see a detail instruction [here](https://daniate.com/2017/03/21/WKWebView%E9%95%BF%E6%8C%89%E5%9B%BE%E7%89%87%E8%AF%86%E5%88%AB%E4%BA%8C%E7%BB%B4%E7%A0%81.html).

And the sample code can be found [here](https://github.com/Daniate/WKWebViewQRcode).